# How to select menu in pyvis network?

Tags: python, networkx, sna, pyvis

[image]

I want to visualize network with selection different nodes. For better understanding the problem attached this code.

```
from pyvis.network import Network
G = nx.Graph()
rels = [
    ["Fred", "George"],
    ["Harry", "Rita"],
    ["Fred", "Ginny"],
    ["Tom", "Ginny"],
    ["Harry", "Ginny"],
    ["Harry", "George"],
    ["Frank", "Ginny"],
    ["Marge", "Rita"],
    ["Fred", "Rita"]
]
G.add_edges_from(rels)

net = Network(notebook=True, height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor = '#222222', font_color = 'white', select_menu=True)
net.from_nx(G)
net.save_graph("networkx-pyvis.html")
```

I use pyvis `select_menu=True` and my net doesn't exist. If I delete `select_menu=True`, my network appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to use select menu in pyvis network?

Passing `cdn_resources='remote'` in `Network` worked for me.

In your case the following should work:

```
net = Network(notebook=True, height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor = '#222222', font_color = 'white', select_menu=True, cdn_resources='remote')
```

Possible reason for this would be that, `pyvis` is not able to find the required cdn resources in our local directory.

Answer (score 0):

**select_menu in Pyvis network**

I tried many options and above solution as well but got below error

```
----> 5 net = Network(notebook=True, height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor = '#222222', font_color = 'white', select_menu=True, cdn_resources='remote')

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'select_menu'
```

Note : same error appears for "filter_menu" as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33890688)